# c# - inherit two classes from one base class gives error 3024

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, inheritance, entity-framework-4.1, poco

I have three tables in my database t1, t2 and t3 and t1 is "base" of t2 and t3. Each table has a column named Id and t2 and t3 has also a column named t1Id.

There are also ForeignKey-Constraints on t1.t1Id and t2.t1Id / t3.t1Id with cardinality 1 to 0..1.

In VisualStudio EF-Modeldesigner I generated the following situation:

[image: Basic picture of the situation]

Indeed there are more columns, but they have nothing to do with my problem ;-). During compile I got two errors with the error code 3024:

```
   Problem in mapping fragments starting at line xy: Must specify mapping for all key properties t1.t1Id of the EntitySet t1s
```

**EDIT:** I use POCO-Classes

I can't see where the problem could be. I tried to solve the problem by adding the ForeignKey-association and navigation-properties without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't add t1id to the derived types, t1id is implied on derived types.

To rebuild the mappings press "Generate Database From Model"

Edit: Put the t1id only on t1, not on T2 and T3

Comment: After deleting UserID I can't compile the project :-(

Comment: @amens: what is UserId?  Use the terminology from your example, or post your original code.  And what error do you get when you try to compile?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant t1Id. The error: `EntityType t1 has no key defined. Define the key`. If I delete on the child-class I got the some error as before

Comment: @BasB Unfortunately this has no effect I still get this dammend error 3024 as descriped in my post. I thought it could be a problem with the POCO-Classes, but reconfiguring to default has no effect, too.